# $\forall x\in [0,1]$, if $f(t)f(t-x)$ is integrable, then $f(t)$ is integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

The original problem (from [here](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~ploh/docs/math/2017-295/01-intro.pdf) problem 8) is:

Let $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$ be a real number. Prove that it is impossible to find a real function $f$ such that
$$f(x)=1+\alpha\int_x^1 f(t)f(t-x) \, dt$$
holds for all $0\leq x\leq1$.

My solution: Integrate both sides for $x$ from $0$ to $1$ and suppose $s=\int_0^1f(x) \, dx$. Then the equality becomes $s=1+\frac{1}{2}\alpha s^2$. Apply AM-GM to finish the proof.

However, my solution works only when $f(x)$ is integrable (on $[0,1]$).

My question is: if the equality in the problem holds, then $\forall x\in [0,1]$, $f(t)f(t-x)$ is integrable, so is it true that $f(x)$ is integrable? If it is not true, is there an explicit counterexample?

For all "integrable" here, I think I mean "Riemann integrable". I have not studied the Lebesgue theory yet.

Comment: Can you explain how you get $s = 1+\frac{1}{2}\alpha s^2$? I think you made a mistake. Note that you are integrating from $x$ to $1$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Just calculations. Also, I tried some specific $f(x)$. The equation always holds.

Comment: can you please show the calculations? I think you made a mistake.

Comment: @mathworker21$\int_{0}^1\int_{x}^1 f(t)f(t-x)dtdx=\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^v f(u)f(v)dudv=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1 f(u)f(v)dudv$. Thinking  it geometrically may help.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Thank you.

Comment: Is an "almost counterexample" good enough? It is a counterexample for all $x$ excepting $0,1$...

Comment: Do you mean 'Let $x \in [0,1]$. If $f(t)f(t-x)$ is integrable, then $f(t)$ is integrable?'? Or 'Suppose $f(t)f(t-x)$ is integrable $\forall x\in [0,1]$. Is $f(t)$ is integrable?' ?

Comment: @BCLC Definitely the second option. The second option is clearly the implicit assumption being made in the "original problem" statement. And the first option is clearly false.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the equality holds for all $x$. In particular at $x=0$ we notice that
$$\|f\|^2_{L^2[0,1]} = \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 \ dx  < \infty.$$
Then by Cauchy-Schwarz for functions,
$$ \int_0^1 |f(x)|\ dx = \langle |f|, 1\rangle_{L^2[0,1]}\leq \|f\|_{L^2[0,1]}\|1\|_{L^2[0,1]} = \|f\|_{L^2[0,1]} < \infty.$$

Thus, as long as $f$ is (Lebesgue) measurable, your proof works.

Comment: Thank you for your work, but if I understand it correctly, it does not answer my question and it can't fully solve the original problem.

Comment: @EricYewenSun No, it doesn't solve it for arbitrary $f$, but if you add the assumption of Lebesgue measurability, then what I am saying is that the equality implies $L^2$ integrability which implies Lebesgue integrability. I don't see how to conclude Lebesgue measurability or Riemann integrability for the original problem

Answer (score 1):

Almost a counterexample, The example below is a counterexample excepting for $x=0,1$ :(
Maybe someone smarter can modify it .

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$.
$$
f(t)=
\left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
1 & \mbox{ if } t =\frac{n}{p}  \mbox{ with } n \in \mathbb N \mbox{ and } p \mbox{ prime } \\
-1& \mbox{ otherwise }
\end{array}
\right.$$

Now, since the set $A=\{ t= \frac{n}{p} :  n \in \mathbb N \mbox{ and } p \mbox{ prime }  \}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ it follows that $f$ is discontinuous everywhere and hence not Riemann integrable.

**Claim:** For all $x \in (0,1)$ the function $f(t)f(t-x)$ is Riemann integrable.

**Proof:**

**Case 1:** If $x \notin \mathbb Q$ then it is easy to see that $f(t)f(t-x)=0 \forall t \in [0,1]$, which is Riemann Integrable.

**Case 2:** If $x =\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb Q$ then it is easy to see that $f(t)f(t-x)=0 \forall t \in [0,1]$.

We claim that in this case, for each such fixed $x$, we can only find finitely many $t \in A$ such that $t+x \in A$.

So let $t= \frac{k}{p}$ be so that $t, t-x \in A$.

We show next that $p|n$. 
Assume by contradiction that $p \nmid n$ then 
$$t-x=\frac{k}{p}-\frac{m}{n}= \frac{kn-pm}{np}$$

Now, since $p|pm$ and $p \nmid kn$, $p$ cannot be reduced from the second fraction. 
Since the second fraction must belong to $A$, and hence must be reduced to a fraction to prime denominator, it follows that $n$ must be reduced and hence 
$$n|kn-pm \Rightarrow n|pm \Rightarrow n|m$$
with the last implication following from $p$ prime and $p \nmid n$ implies $gcd(p,m)=1$.

Therefore $n|m$ and hence $x=\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb Z$ contradiction.

This yields that $p|n$ and hence 
$$t \in \{ \frac{k}{p} : p |n, 1 \leq k \leq p \}=:A_n$$

Now, since $x$ is fixed, so is $n$, and each fixed $n$ has finitely many prime divisors, from where it follows that $A_n$ is finite.

*To complete the proof of Case 2:*

Since there are only finitely many such $t$, it follows that $f(t)f(t-x)=0$ outside this finite set. Therefore, $f(t)f(t-x)$ is Riemann integrable.